# phonegap image download not error

Tags: android, cordova

here i my code:

the image exist at http://www.google.com/trends/resources/2327917647-google-icon.png

i am unable to save the image

it shows error code 1
what is the problem??

```
function gfsuccess(fentry){

    alert(fentry.fullPath+"dircreated")

    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var uri = encodeURI("http://www.google.com/trends/resources/2327917647-google-icon.png");

    fileTransfer.download(uri,fentry.fullPath+"/newimg.png", // //demo_folder
    function(entry) {

        alert("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
    },
    function(error) {

        alert("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    }, 
    false, {

        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
        }
    });
}

function gotfs(fs){

    alert("gotfs"+fs);
    fs.root.getDirectory("demo_folder", {create: true, exclusive: false},gfsuccess,errorHandler);
}

function errorHandler(e){

    alert("Files system error"+e.code);
}
function onDeviceReady() {

    alert("device ready"+navigator.connection.type);
    //external root dir: file:///storage/sdcard0/
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 20*1024*1024/*5MB*/, gotfs, errorHandler);
}

function domLoaded(){

    alert("dom loaded");
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
```

the folder is created ok but i cant seem to get the image..not sure what is going on here

Comment: Maybe it's me but I don't actually see a fileoutputstream to write the image anywhere? You seem to be retrieving the image, then check whether the demo folder exists but I don't see the creation of a temp file which is then written to? Is download supposed to be doing this automatically?

Comment: the fileTransfer.download method showed download it automatically..i am pretty sure may path is faulty..but cant figure out what is the fault

Comment: In native android I had to use File.createTempFile to first create an empty file to write to after, or it would only create the folders and then discard the image after loading it because of an internal write error without any output. Sounds familiar, doesn't it?